# What's a word for being disappointed in a surprising manner?

Tags: word-choice, single-word-requests, synonyms

I know the question a bit vague but that's the only plausible inquiry I could come up with. I wanted to what word can be used if someone is disappointed and they are surprised as to the fact that to start with they never thought the subject matter or the person which disappointed them would have such an effect on them.

Comment: I think the "phrase": *[to be **unexpectedly disappointed in** someone](https://www.google.it/search?q=unexpectedly+disappointed&oq=unexpectedly+disappointed&aqs=chrome..69i57&sourceid=chrome&es_sm=0&ie=UTF-8#q=unexpectedly+disappointed&tbm=bks&tbs=sbd:1)" is probably close to what you're looking for.

Comment: Close enough, I was just looking for a single word, but thank you.

Comment: Other two-word phrases that might suit your purpose are "unpleasantly surprised" and "taken aback." Both indicate surprise (quite clearly) and suggest disappointment (somewhat more subtly). I agree with Mari-Lou A that no single-word choices is entirely satisfactory.

Comment: *Inconceivable!*

Comment: "Blindsided" is the word.

Comment: *Disconcerted*.

Comment: How about dismayed? I don't have enough reputation points to make my own answer.

Answer (score 4):

You might consider *shocked*, which can be used to mean "surprised and upset".

Answer (score 4):

"chagrin" comes to mind.

> distress of mind caused by humiliation, disappointment, or failure. [MW](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/chagrin)
>
> - "To my chagrin, the party ended just as I arrived."
> - "She had gained five pounds over the winter, much to her chagrin."
> - "He decided to get a tattoo, to the chagrin of his parents."

Answer (score 2):

You are **disillusioned** [with someone / something].

From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/disillusioned):

> *disillusioned*  adjective
>
> disappointed in someone or something that one discovers to be less
>   good than one had believed.

Answer (score 1):

"Aghast" is to be struck by terror or amazement, to be shocked (Merriam-Webster).  It is not idiomatic and so would serve for any generic surprise, though it might be slightly more than disappointed.

> Charlie was aghast at the amount of saturated fat in his chocolates.

Comment: Charlie should not have chosen this brand: http://i.imgur.com/JQfYWlx.jpg

Answer (score 0):

I think the word you're looking for is **nonplussed**. From [Oxford Dictionaries Online](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/us/definition/american_english/nonplussed):

> **non·plussed** nänˈpləst *adjective*
>
> 1. (of a person) surprised and confused so much that they are unsure how to react. "he would be completely nonplussed and embarrassed at
>    the idea"
> 2. North American *informal* (of a person) not disconcerted; unperturbed.

Comment: Please tell us where you copied that text from.

Comment: Welcome to the site Allie. I've edited your answer to improve its appearance. Note that Stack Exchange has a particular way of formatting things, including double enters for line breaks. You can press the formatting help button when making a reply for more info.

Comment: tchrist, I added a link.

Comment: This is a great word. Unfortunately, it's been skunked in North America where many people think it means its opposite (as shown above).

Answer (score -1):

No takers for "**discombobulated**?"

Answer (score -3):

Shell-shocked and Gobsmacked might be applicable to your context. A person is said to be shell-shocked when they're confused, shocked or anxious because of a difficult or unexpected situation and hence can't act/think normally. Gobsmacked is very similar where you're so surprised by an event that you lose the tendency to think normally or think at all.