# What's one word for the phrase 'the act of taking your head back on seeing something strange'?

Tags: single-word-requests

I am writing a short story, but I am mostly stuck in one word substitution (as my vocabulary isn't that strong). So I want to know one word for the following phrase —

> the act of taking your head back on seeing something strange (or unexpected)

Sample sentence —

> She turned away and was a little shocked ... (the act of taking your head back on seeing something strange (or unexpected)) ... by the sight of the filled porcelain.

Comment: Do you mean like a double-take (which is a delayed reaction to the strangeness) or an immediate reaction? Also since you've tagged this as a single word request, you should include a sample sentence demonstrating how the word would be used.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Word for Negatively Surprising](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/275052/word-for-negatively-surprising)

Answer (score 20, accepted):

This is not a single word, but it works for your purposes: **taken aback**

This can be used in the figurative sense (and usually is), meaning:

[(MW.com)](https://www.merriam-webster.com/thesaurus/taken%20aback)

> to make a strong impression on (someone) with something unexpected

It's origin is a nautical term:

[(Etymonline)](https://www.etymonline.com/word/aback)

> Now surviving mainly in taken aback, which originally was a nautical
> expression in reference to a vessel's square sails when a sudden
> change of wind flattens them back against the masts and stops the
> forward motion (1754).

Literally, it means being pushed backward (as the head in your example) or halted in your tracks.

Comment: The problem with this phrase is that, despite its appearance (and etymology), it doesn't actually denote any *physical* movement. "Shy", "shrink", "recoil", "start" (as in the other answers) all do.

Comment: Possibly... it doesn't carry much sense of 'shock'...

Comment: @Dan : [to surprise or shock (someone) —usually used as (be) taken aback](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/take%20aback)

Comment: `double-take` is probably a very similar phrase, too long for a single-work-request though.

Comment: @GArthurBrown - I have it more as being surprised by something than shocked... https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/aback

Comment: Well, the Webster definition for the phrase includes shock. Macmillan lists shock before surprise. Cambridge, Oxford Languages, Collins, Longman all include shock.  Dictionary.com includes disconcert.

Comment: @TimPederick I'd say you're completely wrong on that. The word "aback" explicitly denotes physical _motion away_, and unlike the other offerings, _refers to the head_. Shy, shrink, recoil, all refer to the _body_ or _limbs_ moving away, whereas _start_ is an upward jump.

Comment: @Rich: I'm quite taken aback by your disagreement! :-) I exaggerate, of course, but my point is that I would consider "to take aback" to refer to a mental or emotional state, not a physical reaction. Dictionary definitions I've checked aren't explicit either way, but the words they use, like "surprise or shock", don't *necessarily* have a physical motion involved. Honestly I take more reassurance that my view is correct (or at least accepted) by the fact that I got some upvotes…

Comment: @TimPederick Yes, and my answer has more upvotes, so I'm going to suggest that probably more people do associate it with a physical reaction as well as the emotional one. "Physically taken aback" is sometimes used to draw this distinction.

Comment: @GArthurBrown: I wasn't trying to turn it into a popularity contest. Just saying that I'm clearly not alone in thinking of "taken aback" (without "physically" being specified) as primarily mental/emotional, just as you and Rich are not alone in taking it as primarily physical. Hence I don't agree that I'm "completely wrong", as Rich put it.

Answer (score 12):

***Start***, perhaps - To (cause to) make a sudden movement, and related senses.(OED)

> To make a sudden movement, esp. of part of one's body, as to avoid a blow or perceived threat; to flinch or recoil from something in alarm or repugnance. Chiefly with from or with adverbs (as aback, aside, away, back, etc.). Also with the part of the body as subject. (OED)

> To undergo a sudden involuntary movement of the body, resulting from surprise, fright, sudden pain, etc.; (sometimes without implication of actual movement) to feel startled or momentarily perturbed, as at a sudden realization. (OED)

So,...  "*She turned away and started at the sight of the filled porcelain.*"

Comment: I think just _recoil_ would work fine.

Comment: @JohnGordon - yes possibly.  It depends how much physical movement the OP wants to convey.  To my mind, '*recoiling*' generally involves a bigger physical movement than '*starting*', which suggests a more limited physical movement and as much mental as physical shock.

Comment: "Start" doesn't specifically suggest movement *away* from the surprising thing, which is what I *think* the question means by "taking your head back". But as you say, it's less of a movement than "recoil", so it's good for OP to have options so they can pick out their desired shade of meaning.

Comment: It's worth nothing that this usage of start is not idiomatic in spoken English and may even seem a little archaic in literary contexts.

Answer (score 9):

From the full (subscription only) Oxford English Dictionary...

> [**shy**](https://www.oed.com/view/Entry/179090?redirectedFrom=shy%20away#eid22733749) intransitive
> 1: *to take a sudden fright or aversion;
>
> to make a difficulty, ‘boggle’ about doing something;
>
> to **recoil**.*
> 2: (Of a horse) *To **shrink** or start back or aside through sudden fear.*

When ***to shy*** is used with a *person* as the subject, it's usually in more metaphoric negating contexts *(He never shies away from hard work)*. But synonyms such as ***recoil, shrink*** - and passive ***be repulsed / repelled** [by]* - can all be used to convey *rapidly jerk back from [something strange / disgusting / scary]*, if you don't want to potentially liken your subject to a skittish horse.

Comment: _To be taken aback_ is the usual idiom; it doesn't have to be a physical movement.

Answer (score 9):

I'd also say *recoil* or *flinch*:

[recoil](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/recoil): to make a sudden movement away from something esp. because of fear or disgust

[flinch](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/flinch): to withdraw or shrink from or as if from pain

Comment: Good one.  'visually recoiled' or 'physically recoiled' can help make it clear that it's an actual physical reaction.

Answer (score 5):

I think Killing Time's comment fits well, too:

> She turned away and did a **double take** at the sight of the filled porcelain.

A "double take" involves a bit of a delayed reaction, which I envision as having a physical component. Imagine the situation [Merriam-Webster gives as an example](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/double%20take):

> His parents did a double take when he came home with a tattoo.

I imagine that they say "hi" as always and are already turning back to whatever they were doing before he entered, only to turn their heads back, startled, because by then the realization had surfaced that he has this new image on his skin that wasn't there before.

The movement may well involve moving the head backwards as when you try to assess something skeptically, frowning, symbolically increasing the distance to the subject of scrutiny, thinking "wait a minute". You can surely do a double take that way and still look away, if you want to avoid eye contact or don't want to stare; in that case you would freeze for a second, perhaps mentally "replaying" what you saw and considering a proper reaction, without taking a closer look right away.

Comment: Double take isn't a good word for the situation since it implies more taking a second look to verify you saw what you thought you saw, rather than being taken aback and rocked back by the first look. The possible movement back to take that second look in a double take is incidental and doesn't imply the same kind of shock the asker seems to be looking for.

Comment: @Andrew Maybe. M-W simply says "a delayed reaction to a surprising or significant situation" which would fit nicely though. Not sure the expression means specifically "taking" another, double look. For example, one can conceivably do a double take upon *hearing* something.

Answer (score 4):

Perhaps the word you are looking for is **startle**. It hints at physical movement, but not explicitly.

**startle**

*verb:* cause (a person or animal) to feel sudden shock or alarm.

"a sudden sound in the doorway startled her"

**startled**

*adjective:* feeling or showing sudden shock or alarm.

*verb:* **startle**; *3rd person present:* **startles**; *past tense:* **startled**; *past participle:* **startled**; *gerund or present participle:* **startling**

> She turned away and was startled by the sight of the filled porcelain.

<s>I would not write *"She turned away and was startled by the sight of the filled porcelain."* It sounds out of order. I would say *"She was startled by the sight of the filled porcelain and turned away."*</s> **Edit:** Disregard my suggestion about order. It's irrelevant without context. My mistake.

Comment: Possibly a bit emphatic, but nice!

Answer (score 2):

It depends on what you mean by "taking your head back"; *back* can mean either "backwards, away from" or "returning to".

If you mean the first, a backwards movement away from the surprising thing, then the suggestions from other answers—"to shy", "to shrink", "to recoil", "to start"—all fit.

But if you mean the second, a movement where you return your attention to the surprising thing, then the phrase is "double take", and the action is "to do a double take". There is (as far as I know) no single word for this.

Answer (score 2):

Another word used for sudden physical movements is ***jerk***:

> to make a short sudden movement, or to cause someone or something to
> do this:
>
> - "What's wrong?" she asked, jerking her head up. ([Cambridge](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/jerked))

So you could say ***jerked back***

> To physically jerk or bounce off, especially in a backward motion. To move back or away from, especially because of fear or disgust ([WordHippo](https://www.wordhippo.com/what-is/another-word-for/jerk_back.html))
>
> - "What about morals?" I jerked back, like she'd slapped me. ([Newyorker](http://www.newyorker.com/?p=1263351))
> - Suddenly, he jerked back in his chair. ([Longman](https://www.ldoceonline.com/dictionary/jerk))

The expression ***[jerking one's head back](https://www.google.com/search?q=%22jerked%20her%20head%20back%20in%20surprise%22&biw=1372&bih=661&tbm=bks&sxsrf=ALeKk02kL84BUgVuIMZyDH4LwaooM5LRyA%3A1626599647293&ei=3_DzYNyvEcjIgQaNgrHYDA&oq=%22jerked%20her%20head%20back%20in%20surprise%22&gs_l=psy-ab.3...20718.26190.0.27390.3.3.0.0.0.0.435.575.2j4-1.3.0....0...1c.1.64.psy-ab..0.0.0....0.IYs5971z5CA)*** is also possible.

Answer (score 2):

Depending on how strongly your character reacts, I'd suggest [reeled](https://dictionary.cambridge.org/us/dictionary/english/reel):

> Reel:  to waver or fall back (as from a blow)

Your sentence could then be:

> She turned away and *reeled* at the sight of the filled porcelain.

This implies quite a dramatic reaction, though, not just a slight movement of surprise.

Answer (score 1):

#### Goggled at.

If the intended emotion is that of confusion rather than fright or shock, "goggled at" works. It refers to the sort of confused head-bobble where you look at something, jerk your head back, then move it closer to look at it.

"She turned away and goggled at the filled porcelain."